How to use DispatchTime with a published variable?
I'm trying to call
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + UserSession.shared.logoutTimer, execute: {
    UserSession.shared.status = .none
})

Here the logoutTimer is a published variable. I'm changing the UserSession.shared.logoutTimer dynamically but I'm unable to fire the event if this timer is dynamic. It only works on static timer. Can someone advise me how to achieve this.

Your question is unclear, you need to show of your code and explain what and why you are doing.

If you want to action the code you show in SwiftUI, try this:
 .onChange(of: UserSession.shared.logoutTimer) {
     DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + UserSession.shared.logoutTimer, execute: {
         UserSession.shared.status = .none
     })
 }

